# Hibernate: LEFT JOIN FETCH with multiple columns for the join

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, hql

We would like to left outer join two tables in HQL using two columns for the join.

The second column for the join has no relevance at the logical level and doesn't restrict the result set in any way. It's the partition key and is used solely as an optimization to speed up the phyiscal data access.

In SQL it would be something like

```
select * 
from t1 
left outer join t2 
on t1.id = t2.parent_id 
and t1.partion_key = t2.partition_key
```

The following approaches that we tried didn't work:

- We can do an outer join in HQL `left join fetch` and it's possible to specify an additional condition in the join using  `with` but both can't be combined together. This limitation is explicitely mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):
  "Fetch should also not be used together with impromptu with condition".
- Using an additional where condition `t1.partion_key = t2.partition_key` doesn't work because it change the semantics of the query from an outer join to an inner join: when no data matches the condition doesn't hold and the row is ignored.
- Using the oracle syntax `t1.partion_key = t2.partition_key (+)` also doesn't work since it results in a SQL query that mixes the ANSI und Oracle syntax.
- We though about using a combined key but it's not really correct because at the logical level, the key is only `id`. We don't want to let the physical data modelling (partitioning) impact the logical model.

How can we express the desired query with HQL?

Answer (score 5):

1) Since Hibernate [5.1](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16) we can use 'join' on unrelated classes in HQL queries. In this case we can use this HQL query:

```
select 
    p as parent, 
    c as child 
from 
    Parent p 
    left join Child c on c.parentId = p.id and c.partitionKey = p.partitionKey
```

2) Another approach is to modify entities as following (adding two `JoinColumn`s to `children` property in `Parent` entity and replacing `parent` 'many-to-one' relation to simple `parentId` property in `Child` entity):

```
@Entity
public class Parent {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "partition_key")
    private Integer partitionKey;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "partition_key", referencedColumnName = "partition_key")
    })
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "partition_key")
    private Integer partitionKey;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Integer parentId;

    // @ManyToOne
    // private Parent parent;
}
```

Then we can use the following simple JPQL query:

```
select distinct p as parent from Parent p left join fetch p.children c
```

Both queries are translated by Hibernate to like this SQL query:

```
select 
    p.id, 
    p.partition_key, 
    s.id, 
    s.parent_id, 
    s.partition_key 
from 
    parents p 
    left outer join children c on (c.parent_id=p.id and c.partition_key=p.partition_key)
```

Working demo is [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/double-join).

Comment: Is the approach with @JoinColumn applicable for .hbm mappings? We are using Hibernate 5, but with .hbm.

Comment: @ewernli I think you can use two 'column' elements like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202658/5380322)

Comment: @ewernli Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to use table partitioning with Hibernate without composite primary keys, so you really don't have much options.

One thing that comes to my mind is to try to still achieve outer join semantics with an additional where clause and null check:

```
where t1.partion_key = t2.partition_key OR t2.partition_key is null
```

Comment: Right. I forgot to mention that we tried that as well. The results are correct, but Oracle doesn't understand that the join happens on two column and the execution plan doesn't really benefit from partitionning then.

Comment: Got it. Then I don't see any other way than using composite keys, hopefully somebody else would come up with a better idea. Btw, the additional advantage of composite keys for this is that they ensure that partition condition is always automatically included by Hibernate, so you don't have to specify it manually. Personally, I would give it a try.